# Unable to add FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule from @angular/forms@^9.0.0

Tags: angular, angular-forms

```
> "dependencies": {
>     "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
>     "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
>     "@angular/common": "^9.0.0",
>     "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0",
>     "@angular/core": "^9.0.0",
>     "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0",
>     "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
>     "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0",
>     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0",
>     "@angular/router": "^9.0.0",
>     "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
>     "angular-datatables": "^8.0.0",
>     "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
>     "core-js": "^2.5.4",
>     "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
>     "ng2-completer": "^3.0.3",
>     "ng2-smart-table": "^1.5.0",
>     "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
>     "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
>     "primeng": "^9.0.0-rc.4",
>     "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
>     "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
>     "tslib": "^1.10.0",
>     "zone.js": "^0.10.2"   }
```

Above is my Package.json dependencies version.I am using angular 9.0.0.I am trying to add formmodule in app.module.ts.But unable to do so.Even BrowserModule from '@angular/platform-browser'package also showing error in same file.
Below is my app module code

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SearchPageComponent } from './search-page/search-page.component';
import { SearchPageService } from './search-page/search-page.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchPageComponent   
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,BrowserAnimationsModule,FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [SearchPageService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Provide app module code.

Comment: Make sure you have added `BrowserModule, FormsModule` in import section of `app.module.ts`

Comment: @varundhariyal, I have edited my query and put app module code there.

Comment: Kindly show the error message you are getting.

Comment: Module '"../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations"' has no exported member 'BrowserAnimationsModule'.ts(2305)